# LESS Recursive Mixin

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I am trying to create a series of bars which mimic the layout of the signal strength bars on cell phones, much like this:

[image]

Where the bar widths from top to bottom are 100%, 75%, 50%, and 25%

[Here is a plunker with the code](https://plnkr.co/edit/OZL16RgpJQV0Ga61rIDj?p=preview)... the styles assigned in the looping mixin don't seem to be applying to the bar divs as I expected... what have I done wrong?

And here is the code, if you can't be bothered with plunker:

Index.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="bars-container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and style.less:

```
div.bars-container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    .generate-bars(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
        &:nth-child(@{n} - @{i} + 1) {
            width: (@i * 100% / @n);
            height: 2px;
            background-color: green;
            border: 1px solid green;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
        }
        .generate-bars(@n, (@i + 1));
    }
    div {
        .generate-bars(4);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You code produce rather invalid selectors like `:nth-child(4 - 1 + 1)` (note that Less won't do any arithmetic inside selectors since most of operator have different meaning there. Thus if  `:nth-child(4 - 1 + 1)` is supposed to result in `:nth-child(5)` you need first to do your math for a temporary variable and then use the value of that variable in the selector).

Comment: I.e. [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cndiv%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.generate-bars(4)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.generate-bars(%40n%2C%20%40i%3A%201)%20when%20(%40i%20%3D%3C%20%40n)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40j%3A%20%40n%20-%20%40i%20%2B%201%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%3Anth-child(%40%7Bj%7D)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%20width%3A%20(%40i%20*%20100%25%20%2F%20%40n)%3B%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct.generate-bars(%40n%2C%20(%40i%20%2B%201))%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: That (after all) can be simplified to [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22div%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.generate-bars(4)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.generate-bars(%40n%2C%20%40i%3A%20%40n)%20when%20(%40i%20%3E%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.generate-bars(%40n%2C%20%40i%20-%201)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%3Anth-child(%40%7Bi%7D)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctwidth%3A%20(1%20%2B%20%40n%20-%20%40i)%20%2F%20%40n%20*%20100%25%3B%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: Awesome, thank you @seven-phases-max!